# Does the Catholic Church in Turkey celebrate the Feast of the Chair of St Peter at Antioch?

Tags: catholicism, peter, feasts, turkey, antioch

Prior to the changes to the [General Roman Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Roman_Calendar) in 1969, Catholics of the Roman Rite celebrated two Feasts of the [Chair of St. Peter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chair_of_Saint_Peter). The Feast of the Chair of St. Peter at Antioch was celebrated on February 22, and the Feast of the Chair of St Peter at Rome was celebrated on January 18.

Since 1970, the Catholic Church only celebrates the Chair of St. Peter at Rome on February 22.

The Archdiocese of Malta celebrates the [Shipwreck of St Paul](http://catholicsaints.info/saint-paul-the-apostle/) on February 10. St Paul was shipwrecked at Malta around 60 AD.

Since St. Peter, the Prince of the Apostles established his first see at Antioch [(Antakya, Turkey)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antioch), my question is this: Do the Catholic faithful of Turkey celebrate the Feast of the Chair of St. Peter at Antioch in accordance with the general celebration, or according to a local custom?  If they do, what is the day of celebration?

Comment: The celebration of the Shipwreck of St Paul in Malta appears to be out of context in this question, though it is of passing interest.